# why my directory copy endless when run copytree command of shutil?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a directory like this, but when i run `shutil.copytree` copy my current directory to build, it copy the my directory endless?

```py
import shutil
shutil.copytree('.' , './build') #remove build directory before.
```

Directory look like this:
[image]

After run copytree:
build directory is endless, i only wanted copy current directory only.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutil copytree() is called recursively.

You have to add shutil.ignore_patterns('[pattern to build folder]') as an **ignore** argument to your copytree().